# Least number principle

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

I'm really sorry if this question has been asked before, I looked but couldn't find anything.

The least number principle states that every non-empty set of positive integers contains a least element.

I need to find some examples of theorems, involving natural numbers, that are consequences of the least number principle.

One example is given by the Dickson lemma: we have an infinite sequence $l_0,l_1,l_2, \ldots$ of natural numbers and we want to show that exist two indexes $i$ and $j$ such that $i<j$ and $l_i\leq l_j$.

The proof is: let $i^*$ be the minimum of the sequence that exists by the least number principle. Then define $i=i^*$ and $j=i^*+1$.

Thanks!

Comment: What you are calling the least number principle is usually known as the Well-Ordering Principle.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig There is the possibility of confusing this with another statement, which is also called the "Well-Ordering Principle", namely: Every set can be well-ordered.

Answer (score 2):

The principle of induction is a consequence of the least number principle and hence everything, that you can proof via induction. Here is why:

Suppose $N\subseteq \mathbb{N}, 1\in N$ and $\forall n\in N : n+1\in N$. Let $M = \mathbb{N}\setminus N$. Suppose $M$ is non-empty. Then it has a least element $m$. Then $m-1\notin M$, so $m-1\in N$. But then $m\in N$. (Contradiction). Hence $M$ is empty, therefore $N = \mathbb{N}$.

Similarly, you can prove statements normally proved by induction. Let's show, that every positive integer greater than $1$ has a prime divisor: Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ be greater then $1$. Then $n$ has a divisor greater than $1$ (namely $n$), hence it has a least divisor $p$ greater then $1$. If $p$ is not prime, then it has a divisor $t$ with $1<t<p$. But in that case $t$ is divisor of $n$, greater then $1$ with $t<p$ (Contradiction, since $p$ was minimal with that property). Therefore $p$ is prime and $n$ has a prime divisor.

Comment: Thanks, what you say is true. But I probably didn't write the question in the right way. What I'm looking for are examples of theorem using the following fact: ''every function from natural to natural has a minimum'' (is a theorem that follow from the least number principle)

Comment: How do you define $m-1$ and prove that it exists without using induction?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#:~:text=it%20is%20mistakenly%20printed%20in%20several%20books%5B22%5D%20and%20sources%20that%20the%20well-ordering%20principle%20is%20equivalent%20to%20the%20induction%20axiom%2E